# Passing COM and accessing components between HTML window

Tags: javascript, html, visual-c++, com

I have a 2 HTML pages. Page 1 has a COM component, say COMP1. How can I pass this to page 2 when I use `window.ShowModelessDialogue`? I tried something like this:

```
window.showModelessDialog("Page2.html", COMP1, "....");
```

but on the Page 2 when I say `window.dialogArguments` it says `undefined`. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. This can be as below.

```
 var args = { parentWindow: window };
 window.showModelessDialog("Page2.html", args,"...");
```

Here the Window is the parent page which contains the com component COMP1.
In the page2.html add the below code to get the com component COMP1.

```
 if (typeof window.dialogArguments == 'object' && window.dialogArguments !== null) {
           var parentArgs = window.dialogArguments;
            if (parentArgs.parentWindow !== null) {
                        pWindow= parentArgs.parentWindow;
                        comComp = pWindow.COMP1;
          }
 }
```

This worked for me.